# Java JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError C char pointer to pointer

Tags: java, c++, types, java-native-interface

Hi I am currently working on a project where a C++ framework shall be integrated into a java program, thus I started exploring JNI. I am currently struggling with the type conversions and what argument types should be declared in the java native method since I am new to C++.

In the cpp-file I have the following method:

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

My corresponding java class looks like this:

```
public class JniTest {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("plain2snt");
}

public JniTest() {

    char[][] arguments = new char[][] {"resourceFile1.txt".toCharArray(), "resourceFile2.txt".toCharArray()};
    main(2, arguments);
}

public native int main(int argc, char[][] argv);

}
```

And the header file for the java class is the following:

```
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class testPackage_JniTest */

#ifndef _Included_testPackage_JniTest
#define _Included_testPackage_JniTest
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     testPackage_JniTest
 * Method:    main
 * Signature: (I[[C)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_testPackage_JniTest_main
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jobjectArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

When I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
testPackage.JniTest.main(I[Ljava/lang/String;)I
    at testPackage.JniTest.main(Native Method)
    at testPackage.JniTest.<init>(JniTest.java:14)
    at testPackage.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

I already used google, JNI API reference, etc. to look up the type matching between Java and C++ but could not find how to handle a char pointer to pointer type in Java. What would be the actual type definition in the Java class for the argv argument to match the char** in the cpp framework?

Answer (score 0):

When JVM tries to invoke native method - it expects that you've implemented it as function pointed at header generated with `javah`. I.e. your library somewhere must contain

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_testPackage_JniTest_main
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jobjectArray) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

And caught exception is a claim, that there is no implementation for native method.

Next, it is much more convenient to pass `arguments` not as array-of-array-of-char but just as array of `String`.

```
public JniTest() {

    String[] arguments = new String[] {"resourceFile1.txt", "resourceFile2.txt"};
    main(2, arguments);
}

public native int main(int argc, String[] argv);

}
```

In C++ you can obtain args in next way:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_testPackage_JniTest_main (JNIEnv *, jobject thiz, jint argc, jobjectArray argv) {
    for(jsize i = 0; i < env->GetArrayLength(argv); i++) {
        jstring str = (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement(argv, i);
        const char *c_str = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, NULL);
        /* do whatever you want with c_str */
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, c_str);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I added the JNIEXPORT jint ... to my library. At least this is what I think I did by implementing this method in the cpp-file  (given the third piece of code you provided and adapted it) and recompiled the cpp file to a dll. This worked fine, but I still get the samme error. Are there any further steps that need to be taken or do I misunderstand something about the JNI API and its workflow?

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem. It was just the case that in my Java class I did not initialize an object of that class and called the native main-method. So I basically just changed JniTest() to public JniTest() { String[] arguments = new String[] {"resourceFile1.txt", "resourceFile2.txt"}; JniTest test = new JniTest(); test.main(2, arguments); }